# SMF Forum Upgrade - 49Gb and 366,000+ files in attachments

Tags: php, forum, smf

So I've got a problem with an SMF forum upgrade I'm trying to attempt. The forum is 1.1.6 and I am wanting to upgrade this to v2+.

I've got the upgrade script from the SMF website however I'm experiencing what seems to be a unique error.

In the existing forum I have 49Gb of attachments, all stored inside 366,000+ files all under one folder.

Obviously my upgrade process is failing due to timeouts.

I am trying to see whatever options are available for me to get this upgrade done, while still keeping these attachments?

Comment: one off? increase the timeout to infinite `set_time_limit(0)`

Comment: Thanks @Dagon - I assume that this is the php.ini setting you are referring to here? It's definitely just a once off run so that the upgrade can be performed... Here's hoping it doesn't take more than a week to run to completion. The other concern is if there is a memory overhead and that the upgrade script will actually release memory as it runs.

Comment: that function can be just put in the upgrade scrip, or you can tweak php.ini if you prefer. php.ini its `max_execution_time = 0`

Comment: Good point. I'll add it into the script itself and try give it a run that way!

Comment: its a little safer if its an option ;-) if your on a shared host this may not work for you

Comment: Just an update on this in case anyone has the same problem, using Dagon's suggestion of set_time_limit(0) worked perfectly.